# How to set the initial width of a dockable window in Notepad++

Tags: c#, winforms, notepad++

I'm developing a plugin for Notepad++ in C# that opens a couple of dockable forms.

I'd like to set the initial width of such forms (each form has a different width) so that they look nicer to the user and don't grab unused space to the editor.

I'm using this snippet to open the form: http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/45764/How-to-open-a-dockable-window-in-Notepad

My form has already predefined the initial size I want to give but it seems that Notepad++ doesnt' care about that.

Please help!!

Thank you very much

Best

cghersi

Comment: Did you already made some effort examining classes **DockingCont**, **DockingManager** or **DockingSplitter**? Did you attempt to debug/trace them to see how tool window width is initiated? Is something not working properly in that code? Please post here research on N++ source you made so far before you ask help from the community.

Comment: Thank you miroxlav, I just forgot to say that I'm developing the plugin in C#; I tried to give a look to the classes you mentioned in C++ but unfortunately the approach is quite different and I didn't found any notable help there :(

Comment: Cristiano, I understand this can be difficult to find out without starting a debugger and carefully checking the entire process of dockable window creation by tracing execution. I can't help you with that at the moment. Maybe you can ask [directly in Notepad++ forums](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/resources.html) - see links on that page.

Comment: Hi @miroxlav unfortunately I've already tried to ask in the forum without success :(. I've found that those dimensions are driven by configuration file of Notepad++, so now I'm trying to changing this configuration file but still I cannot reload the configuration in realtime so I'm stuck at the moment